# Compile type-error once I upgraded to Xcode iOS >= 16

Tags: swiftui

I've tried splitting up my struct code here. I am still getting the type-error compile warning. I'm not sure what part of my code is causing it. I have a detailviewcontroller and a delete post code in another script that's part of this `var Body View`. My error is coming from my:

```
var body: some View{
```

What else can I do to simplify this or did I get off somewhere? This code worked before  upgraded xcXode to support iOS >= 16

```
extension PlotForm {

    struct Part1View: View {
        var body: some View {
            ForEach(viewDataBase.items, id: \.id ) { item in NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailViewController(item: item)
               , label: {
//                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(item.Field)
                        Text(item.dataCollectionInfo).font(.caption).foregroundColor(.gray)
                        Text("Range " + item.Range + " and Row " + item.Row).font(.caption).foregroundColor(.gray)
                        Text(item.Comments)
//                    } //vstack
                   
               } // label
            ) //navigationlink
           }.onDelete(perform: deletePost)//.environmentObject(ViewDataBase())//foreach

        }//var body view
    }//part1view
    
}// plotform extension

struct HomeView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        PlotForm()
    }//var body
}// home view
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can add a section. It also makes my form look nicer too. Win-win for me. here's my code:

```
 ForEach(viewDataBase.items, id: \.id ) { item in
      Section(header: Text(item.Field)) {
           NavigationLink(destination: DetailViewController(item: item)){

             //Function to add text()

           }//navigationlink
      }//section
 }.onDelete(perform: deletePost)  //foreach
```